# laravel 5.8 custom user registration redirects back to the form not loggin in

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5.8, user-registration

when i try to register my new members it redirects back to form

i have built a new table for members and class extended authenticatable trait but when i try to register the new member it doesn't register any new member it just redirects back to the same form without any error.

```
use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest:member');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application registration form.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function showRegistrationForm()
    {
        return view('frontend.auth.member_register');
    }


    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
        $member = $this->create($request->all());
//        dd($request->all());
        $this->guard()->login($member);
        return redirect($this->redirectPath());

    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:members'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    protected function create(Request $request)
    {

       return Member::create([
            'name' => $request['name'],
            'email' => $request['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($request['password'])
        ]);

    }



    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard('members');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's redirecting because some error exception is being thrown in Handler.php in Exceptions folder by default it redirects to home in handler.php .Use throw($e) in the Handler.php file to check error. You can find error logged also in laravel.log file in the storage folder

Comment: but how can i do that? plz help me. my form is just redirecting to the same registration form. without any error.

Comment: As I said in App\Exceptions\Handler.php in handle method add dd ($e->getMessage()) at first line .Please check if it going to that method first.